# Split array value and use it as key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 102 [30:27]
    [1] => 110 [29:28]
    [2] => 103 [30:27]
)
```

The output I need is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [102] => 30:27
    [110] => 29:28
    [103] => 30:27
)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: is `102 [30:27]` value of `[0]` key or you write here for explanation? you can chnage array value to key by using `array_flip()` array function in php

Comment: But what i need is not flip, what i want is take-off the key from first array and make the value as key and value example, [0] => 102 [30:27]  and change to [102] => 30:27...is clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is consistent then is there any need for expensive regex? Here's the [working version](https://eval.in/79060).

```
$array = array(
    '102 [30:27]',
    '110 [29:28]',
    '103 [30:27]'
);

$new = array();

array_walk($array, function($element) use (&$new) {
    $parts = explode(" ", $element);
    $new[$parts[0]] = trim($parts[1], ' []');
});

var_dump($new);
```

Comment: That is absolutely perfect answer, Thanks Men.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array, use a regular expression to capture both the number and value, and then build a new array with the number as the index:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('~(\d+)\s+\[(.*)]~', $value, $matches)) {
        $index = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : $key;
        $value = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : $key;
        $result[$index] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/79057)

---

If the array values are always delimited by a single space, then a regular expression isn't necessary. You could use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split the array value with space as a delimiter and then get the index and value to build the new array:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $key => & $value) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $value);
    $index = $parts[0];
    $result[$index] = substr($parts[1], 1, -1);
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [102] => 30:27
    [110] => 29:28
    [103] => 30:27
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/79066)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$new_arr=array();


foreach($b as $k=>$v)
{
    $v=explode(' ',$v);
    //var_dump($v);
    $v[1]=str_replace(array('[',']'),array('',''),$v[1]);
    $new_arr[$v[0]]=$v[1];
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array ( [102] => 30:27 [110] => 29:28 [103] => 30:27 )
```